# mount.nfs: assigning subnets in /etc/export is not working

Tags: nfs, centos7, subnet

I have installed nfs-server on centos
and edited my `/etc/exports` as follows

`/data 10.25.0.0/25(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`.

when I try to connect from my client with ip address `10.25.44.144`, the connection is refused.

but when I edit `/etc/exports` with the exact ip `10.25.44.144`, mount works.

but I actually want to accept request from any client in the subnet `10.25.*.*`

how would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you exportfs -ra after editing your /etc/exports ? https://linux.die.net/man/8/exportfs

Comment: yes, of course. I guess it is subnet notation I am having problem with. `10.25.0.0/25` covers ip from 10.25.0.1 to 10.25.0.25. that does not cover everything in the subnet `10.25.*.*`

Comment: https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/10.25.0.0/25, yeah totally.

If you wish to cover 10.25.*.*, you could use a /16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, reading https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html before can be a good thing to do.

Keep in mind that 10.25.0.0/25 only covers https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/10.25.0.0/25

```
First IP 10.25.0.1
Last IP 10.25.0.126
```

If you wish to cover 10.25.44.144, you are going to need to use either a direct ip as you mention before (can be a solution), or extend your /25 to a /18

https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/10.25.0.0/18

```
First IP 10.25.0.1
Last IP 10.25.63.254
```

I would recommend you to keep somewhere at work/home that [sheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html)